# Force flex element not to grow in cross-axis direction

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm making a page with a vertical menu using `display: flex;`. I want the menu's width to fit snuggly around a few buttons, without having to use a fixed width.

However, I also want the menu box to have a status message, which can have quite a long text. I'd like this status-div to have the width of the menu, while not forcing the menu container to grow its width. Instead, the status-div should grow its height and wrap the text.

Explaining this in words is pretty difficult, so I suggest you checkout out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bXL3q/

Note the difference when setting `.statusmessage` to `display: none;`.

Any ideas, or is what I'm trying to do not feasible? ..should it be?

---

What I've tried:

- `width: 100%` fails, obviously it just assumes the parent width
- `width: -webkit-min-content` sort of works, but it makes the element too narrow
- `flex-basis` and `flex-grow` affect the height of the element, and do nothing to affect the width
- `position: absolute` will solve the width issues, but now I have no way to define the height of the status-div.. (for the purpose of forcing a scroll bar in windows with small height - instead it will just flow over the button elements)

---

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.page {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.menu {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.somechildren {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.menu>* {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.separate {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.statusmessage {
  background-color: magenta;
  align-self: flex-end;
  /*display: none;*/
}
```

```html
<div class=menu>
  <div class=somechildren>I'd like the menu's</div>
  <div class=somechildren>width to fit nicely</div>
  <div class=somechildren>around these children</div>

  <div class=separate></div>

  <div class=statusmessage>
    While forcing this status message to wrap and grow its height, without affecting the width of the container.
  </div>
</div>
<div class=page>
  The page
</div>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You were almost there with `width`. What you need to do is set `width` *and* `min-width` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bXL3q/3/)):

```css
.statusmessage {
 width:0; /* Collapses .statusmessage so it doesn't affect column width */
 min-width:100%; /* Expands .statusmessage to width of column */
}
```

The `width` can be (and probably should be) set to a value other than `0`. It should just be the minimum width of the column or smaller. So use a value that works for you.

I've tested this on Chrome and Firefox and seems to work in both. Now, is it *supposed* to work? I'm not sure, I haven't read into [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) that much (it could be undefined). Make sure to test in all browsers you need it to work in. (And check the spec to see if this behavior is undefined/incorrect.)

Comment: Thats.. amazing :P The statusmessage's width is used to calculate the width of the parent, and afterwards the min-width of 100% is applied. Effectively, the width acts as a minimum width in case the other elements are small, and the min-width property defines the 'real' width.

Comment: Chrome 36, Firefox 31 and IE 11 are all playing ball. Cheers!

Comment: Derp, our special friend IE11 is not playing ball after all. I'll max-width for IE specifically.

Comment: Man you saved me today. This sound like an awfully good and weird trick.

Answer (score 3):

`width: 0; min-width: 100%;` didn't work for me.

Instead, I set

```
position: relative;
```

on the flex child and wrapped its contents in an inner div with

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

This prevents the contents from contributing to the flex container size while still matching the cross-axis size determined by the rest of the flex children.

Comment: Wrapping the flex child's content in an inner div worked for me, without changing styling. Thank you. (`width: 0; min-width: 100%;` didn't work for me, either)

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was that [the default value](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp) of `align-items` is `stretch`. So the items stretch out the cross axis by default.

You can either set `align-items: flex-start` or `align-self: flex-start` for the single flex child.

The [visual here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-align-items) is quite illustrative.